# How to select row of data by list of data

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table that has 3 columns. I want to select data by list of data.

```
Table 1

key1    key2     value
 12       A        100
 15       A        150
 17       C         56
 13       D        600
 12       C        100
 10       B         80
```

I have this list as key to select:

```
key1   key2
12      A
17      C
13      D
```

and the result should be:

```
100
 56
600
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear to me what you mean with "list of data", but if those are two tables, you can do:

```
select value
from table1
where (key1, key2) in (select key1, key2
                       from table2);
```

You can also supply the values directly:

```
select value
from table1
where (key1, key2) in ( (12,'A'), (17,'C'), (13,'D') );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
select value from table1 where CONCAT(key1,key2) in (Select CONCAT(key1,key2)  from table2)
```

Comment: That would give wrong results if you have `12,'1'` in the table and `1,'21'` in the list of values.

Answer (score 0):

There's no meaning for 'list of data' in SQL. But if you want to display the result that you mentioned above. Use this code-

Select value from Table 1 Where (key1,key2) in ((12,'A'), (17,'C'),(13,'D')) ;

Answer (score -1):

```
select 
    value 
from 
    Table1
where
    key1 in (12, 17, 13)


select 
    value 
from 
    Table1
where
    key1 in (select key1 from TableKeys)
```